# Transformar float ou double em data dentro de uma lambda

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, expressões-lambda

No BD tem um campo com um valor float, que na verdade é a quantidade de dias a partir da data **28/12/1800**, que a linguagem de programação Clarion armazena. Bem, tenho um serviço **REST** que é consumido por um App Android. O que passa é que eu gostaria de serializar esse campo, mas já como data. Se faço fora da lambda funciona(teste), só que preciso transforma dentro da expressão e não sei como eu faço isso: O comando é?

```
var dt = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(79018).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Com esse comando `dt = 02/05/2017`. Mas preciso carregar uma propriedade do meu DTO e dá erro que o **LINQ** não dá suporte para `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`
Minha lambda é essa:

```
lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        //.Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                        //.Join(contexto.ItensLibs, lib => lib.IdOrcamento, itens => itens.IdOrcamento, (lib,itens) => new { lib, itens})
                        .Where(a => a.FlagLiberacao == 1)
                        .Select(libera => new LiberacaoDTO
                        {
                            TipoVenda = libera.TipoVenda,
                            IdOrcamento = libera.IdOrcamento,
                            Juros = libera.Juros.ToString(),
                            Entrada = libera.Entrada.ToString(),
                            Acrescimo = libera.Acrescimo.ToString(),
                            Desconto = libera.Desconto.ToString(),
                            Mensagem = libera.Mensagem,
                            DataLib = new DateTime(1800,12,28).AddDays(libera.DataLib).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),//ERRO AQUI
                            Vencimento = libera.Vencimento.ToString(),
                            Vendedor = libera.Vendedor,
                            Cliente = libera.Cliente,
                            Filial = libera.Filial
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Não sei o porquê da negativação, pois a pergunta não é ampla. Como eu discordei de dois caras outro dia, sinto que eles me negativam, sempre, independente da pergunta estar ou não dentro dos critérios do site. Mente miúda essas. Pessoas levam comentários para lado pessoal sempre, desrespeitando as regras do site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É impossível, porque o Entity Framework não sabe como traduzir isto para uma expressão SQL.

Existem duas opções bem claras:

#### 1. Materializar os dados da consulta antes de fazer o *select*

```
lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                .Where(a => a.FlagLiberacao == 1)
                .ToList() // <- A query é materializada para a memória aqui
                .Select(libera => new LiberacaoDTO
                {
                    // Demais campos
                    DataLib = new DateTime(1800,12,28).AddDays(libera.DataLib)
                                                      .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                }).ToList();
```

#### 2. Alterar a informação fora do *select*

```
lista = contexto.Liberacoes
            .Where(a => a.FlagLiberacao == 1)
            .ToList()
            .Select(libera => new LiberacaoDTO
            {
                // Demais campos
                DataLibOriginal = libera.DataLib,
            }).ToList();

lista.ForEach(e => e.DataLib = 
               new DateTime(1800,12,28).AddDays(e.DataLibOriginal).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```